# The load test stops before the specified duration

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I'm using a Stepping thread group for a load test

[image]

This is the configuration of stepping thread group.
Instead of running for 4 hours, it is stopping after it is run for 17 minutes. What could be the reason?

Comment: any errors? how is "Action to be taken after a Sampler error" configured?

Comment: There aren't any errors. I think it is because of the the system metrics. The CPU utilization is way too high.

Comment: Could you be more specific and show us your Test Plan? Maybe you have some loop in script that ends, or use CSV Data set but it doesn't have enough data in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add [Runtime Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller) as a parent of your test to enforce running time, in your case Runtime in Seconds = 14400 (4 Hours 60*60*4)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the config for the "Stepping thread group" under **"threads every"** and set the time limit to small value (20 sec) and **"Using ramp-up"** as total rampup time required(300 sec)